# Knapsack Problem on java - Output always Objective Function

Tags: java, cplex, knapsack-problem

**Hello**, i'm trying to create and solve a simple knapsack problem with only 1 bin using java and cplex 12.8. I don't understand why it always gives in output the value of objective function.
Here is my full code:

```
    public static void solveModel(){       

        try {

            n_obj = 5;
            int capacity = 4

            int[] profits = new int[n_obj];
            for(int i = 0; i < n_obj; i++ ){
                weight[i] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, n_obj/2 + 1);
                profits[i] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 12);
            }


            for(int i = 0; i < weight.length; i++){
                System.out.println("Weight " + i + ":\t" + weight[i]);
                System.out.println("Profit " + i + ":\t" + profits[i]);

            }

            IloCplex model = new IloCplex();
            IloNumVar x = model.boolVar();



            IloLinearNumExpr obj = model.linearNumExpr();
            for(int i = 0; i < n_obj; i++){
                obj.addTerm(profits[i], x);
            }

            //obj function
            model.addMaximize(obj);

            //constraints

            for(int i = 0; i < n_obj; i++){
                model.addLe(model.prod(weight[i], x), capacity) ;
                model.addEq(x, 1);

            }

            if (model.solve()) {

                System.out.println("Obj = " + model.getObjValue());
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Problem not solved");
            }

            model.end();



        } catch (IloException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I set n_obj and capacity to fixed values to make it as simple as possible.
The output is everytime this:

```
Weight 0:   1
Profit 0:   2
Weight 1:   1
Profit 1:   11
Weight 2:   2
Profit 2:   2
Weight 3:   1
Profit 3:   7
Weight 4:   2
Profit 4:   6
Found incumbent of value 28.000000 after 0.00 sec. (0.00 ticks)

Root node processing (before b&c):
Real time             =    0.00 sec. (0.00 ticks)
Parallel b&c, 8 threads:
  Real time             =    0.00 sec. (0.00 ticks)
  Sync time (average)   =    0.00 sec.
  Wait time (average)   =    0.00 sec.
                      ------------
Total (root+branch&cut) =    0.00 sec. (0.00 ticks)
Obj = 28.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for those who are, or will be, interested... i solved by myself.
The declaration of the boolean variable has been done in this way:

```
IloNumVar[] x = new IloNumVar[n_obj];
for (int i = 0; i < n_obj; i++) {
//x[i] = model.numVar(0, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, IloNumVarType.Bool, "x[" + i + 
//"]");
    x[i] = model.boolVar();
}
```

And i modified the constraints:

```
 IloLinearNumExpr lin = model.linearNumExpr();
        for (int i = 0; i < n_obj; i++) {
            //model.addLe(model.prod(weight[i], x[i]), capacity);
            lin.addTerm(x[i], weight[i]);
        }

        model.addLe(lin, capacity, "Constraints");
```

I know it was a simple Knapsack problem, but i'm a cplex beginner and i hope it will be useful to other people.

Have fun

Answer (score 0):

CPLEX computed an optimal solution to your problem, with objective value 28.

By default, CPLEX runs in a completely deterministic way. That is, when run multiple times under the same conditions (same problem to solve, same machine, etc.), CPLEX will always return exactly the same results.  So there is no reason to expect different solutions when running your program multiple times.

Comment: Maybe I explained in the wrong way. The problem is that with any list of values, it always gives in output the sum of profits. I think I have a mistake in the initialization of Boolean variable